# install windows service through vb6 app

Tags: .net, vb6

I made a windows service application "Windows service"

After that i made a Config screen which is class library ".dll"

Through that Config screen im able to /Install/Uninstall/Start/Stop my Service.

Everything works great using .net .

When i reference and call that .dll from vb6 application it wont Install service. 
For installation i use standard code

```
   If sUser = Nothing Then
            Dim hSvc As Integer = CreateService(hSCM, ServiceName, DisplayName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, PathService, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)

            If hSvc = 0 Then
                CloseServiceHandle(hSvc)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            CloseServiceHandle(hSvc)
            CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)

        Else
            Dim hSvc As Integer
            Try
                hSvc = CreateService(hSCM, ServiceName, DisplayName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, PathService, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, sUser, sPassword)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


            If hSvc = 0 Then
                CloseServiceHandle(hSvc)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            CloseServiceHandle(hSvc)
            CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)

        End If
```

Comment: Why, again, you do this? .Net has installUtil.exe - use that

Comment: I cant find any example of installing service through code by using InstallUtil.exe. 

I can install without problems but i need to have code for installation through click

Comment: .net has Service Installer project which you can use to create the service. You can use .config file to set your variables and during install your service installer exe can read from there and register with the name given in .config. To install or uninstall use installutil.exe - it comes with .net framework. Using in code - no issue. Just start the process with command line. installutil is command line ustility